# How to shrink a screenshot to fit in a smaller view or button?

Tags: ios

I have some .pngs which are screenshots of an iPhone.

I'd like to display them in a UIImageView and in a button, how can I shrink them down so that they fit within the size of the view/button but all the contents are still visible.

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"screenshot.png"]];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200, 200);
    view.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

or

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"carouselPage.png"];
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200, 200);
button.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

If I use other .pngs (which are smaller) then they are appearing, but if I use the screenshot.png (which was obtained via Xcode's Organizer screenshot functionality) nothing at all is appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the scaling of the image to ensure it's all going to be shown and fit within the view

```
view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

I would assume you should still see the screenshot.png though but just not correctly.